# Developing for Win 7 set to 32bit

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working a 'mature' product that was previously migrated from XP and I was instructed to set my environment to 32 bits. I'm having trouble with wParam and lParam. Since I'm using 32 bit development are these set at 32 bit because of the environment or are they 64 bit because of the Win7 platform?

Comment: There are 32 and 64 bit versions of Windows XP, Vista, 7, and even 8.

Answer (score 4):

`WPARAM` and `LPARAM` are *pointer-sized* data types.  `WPARAM` is an alias for `UINT_PTR`, and `LPARAM` is an alias for `LONG_PTR`.  See MSDN:

[Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx)

Pointers are 32-bit if your project is compiled as a 32-bit executable, and are 64-bit if your project is compiled as a 64-bit executable.

So, to answer your question, `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` will be 32-bit because you are compiling your project into a 32-bit executable (which will run as 32-bit on a 64-bit machine if the [WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384249.aspx) emulator is installed).

Comment: Thanks. This was what I thought but I'm getting some strange numbers.

Comment: Didn't know about the various versions of Windows. I'm an old UNIX & C doggie and got tapped because this project is mostly on C - and some C++ and a decent C flogger wasn't to be found amongst the Off Shore talent. A real mish mash of coding styles.